Selecting rows based on two columns condition padas dataframe
I have below a panda dataframe. I want to make subdataframes based on some conditions. If the typeId ==15 then take all the rows before with only typeId ==1 and result ==1 and save it into a subdataframe.




typeId
result




1
2
3


2
4
1


3
1
1


4
1
1


5
15
1


6
3
4


7
2
1


8
1
1


9
1
1


10
15
1


11
4
4


12
3
3



I should have two subdataframes the first is




typeId
result




3
1
1


4
1
1


5
15
1



And the second is




typeId
result




8
1
1


9
1
1


10
15
1




Can you please format examples nicely?

Sorry for the mistakes. I have updated the quastion

What exactly is your question? Have you tried to do this and run into a problem? Or are you just asking how to implement this in Python from scratch, using Pandas?

Code
To get rows that match all conditions that exist above 15, based on 15, use the following code (Rows that meet the condition even if they are not adjacent to 15 will be imported)
cond1 = df['typeId'].eq(15)
grp = cond1.cumsum() - cond1
cond2 = df['typeId'].eq(1) & df['result'].eq(1)
cond3 = cond1.groupby(grp).transform(any)
out = [d for _, d in df[cond1 | (cond2 & cond3)].groupby(grp)]

out:
[   typeId  result
 3       1       1
 4       1       1
 5      15       1,
     typeId  result
 8        1       1
 9        1       1
 10      15       1]


If you want to extract only rows that meet the condition adjacent to 15 based on 15, please use the following code (Get consecutive rows 1-1 adjacent to 15).
cond1 = df['typeId'].eq(15)
grp = cond1.cumsum() - cond1
cond2 = df['typeId'].eq(1) & df['result'].eq(1)
cond3 = df['typeId'].mask(cond2).bfill().eq(15)
out = [d for _, d in df[cond3].groupby(grp)]


If you want to keep only contiguous rows:
res = []

for i, g in df.groupby((df["typeId"].eq(15))[::-1].cumsum()):
    g = g[(g["typeId"].eq(15) | (g["typeId"].eq(1) & g["result"].eq(1)))]
    if not g.empty:
        m = g.index.to_series().diff().fillna(1).ne(1).cumsum()
        m = m[m == m.max()].index
        g = g.loc[m]
        res.append(g)

for df in res:
    print(df)

    typeId  result
8        1       1
9        1       1
10      15       1
   typeId  result
3       1       1
4       1       1
5      15       1


You can achieve this with a simple groupby. Identify the stretches of typeId==1/result==1, group with the following row (with a reverse cumsum), only keep the group if the last typeId==15:
# identify stretches of typeId==1/result==1
m = df['typeId'].eq(1) & df['result'].eq(1)

# group with following row
# only keep it last typeId==15
out = [g for _,g in df.groupby((~m)[::-1].cumsum(), sort=False)
       if g['typeId'].iloc[-1] == 15]

Output:
[   typeId  result
 3       1       1
 4       1       1
 5      15       1,
     typeId  result
 8        1       1
 9        1       1
 10      15       1]

NB. if you want to ensure that the output DataFrames have rows with 1s, change the filtering condition to if len(g)>1 and g['typeId'].iloc[-1] == 15.
Intermediates:
    typeId  result      m  group keep
1        2       3  False      8     
2        4       1  False      7     
3        1       1   True      6    |
4        1       1   True      6    |
5       15       1  False      6    X
6        3       4  False      5     
7        2       1  False      4     
8        1       1   True      3    |
9        1       1   True      3    |
10      15       1  False      3    X
11       4       4  False      2     
12       3       3  False      1     

